# What do I need in the backend to make an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a call from Javascript to a backend function.  What is the technical name for it? is it called a restfull service? is it just a webpage?

All i need to do is call something and pass a few variables in, the something will return me a value.  So I need to call a global function through the web.  The server will be located in another organisation.  I can't remember what the technical name for it would be..

would you call it a Soap request? Restful service? or just a plain website that I can pass variables as query string values and it just creates an empty web page with the result?

Ta

Comment: a "webservice call" or just an "ajax call" seems apropos; your others are more-specific

Comment: endpoint, possibly?

Comment: I would call it an endpoint. If it "follows RESTful principles" then it's a "REST endpoint". If it uses the SOAP protocol then it's a "SOAP endpoint". Most quick-and-dirty APIs these days use JSON as the serialization format so you might call it a "JSON API endpoint". If you're using JSONP then it's a "JSONP endpoint"

Answer (score 0):

You call it an api request. How that request is handled will be up to whoever writes the service.

You can read up on the specifics here.
https://www.programmableweb.com/api-university/what-are-apis-and-how-do-they-work

The service you make the request to might be using soap or Restful architecture and it's important to know which one so you make the request correctly. Read the documentation or talk to whoever build the service to get a better understanding of what parameters and endpoints you have at your disposal.